# Arima modeling with limited data

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

Our 250 weekly datapoints are shown in the figure, along with correlograms of 1st differences.

Are we correct to conclude, from overdifferenced correlogram, that for this process we should have much more data points before we may expect results from arima modeling? Logtransform is not helping the situation.

We have no more data than shown, and we need to find a credible stochastic model for this process. Not perfect, just credible for use in Monte carlo risk methods.

We understand already that from spectral analysis we should not expect info on the low frequency that is visible in the plot, due to limited data. Does the same problem limit the results possible with Arima modeling?

Thanks for your expertise. 
[image: Time series]

[image: Acf]

Comment: Did you try an (0,1,1) model? At first glance, that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: @zbicyclist: Thanks, could you explain a bit why it looks like that to you?

Comment: Ok I see now your reasons, thanks so much for pointing a direction!